# Messing up the Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, provisioning

I have been developing an app that uses push notifications. I have been messing around ALOT trying to fix the stupid provisioning stuff, and I really don't know what's what anymore.

I managed to fix the whole development push notifications. And now, we are close to release. However, the switch to Production notification didn't go as smooth as expected. And I still don't really understand the whole provisioning-thing.

I thought I just had to switch out the .pem file with a new one, generated from a new .cer and .p12 file, aswell as remove the "sandbox" from the url it's trying to connect to. This just resulted in "Failed to connect: 0" in my .php sending the push.

.php

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'dp.pem')
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if(!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
```

After messing around with the .p12 and .cer and .cert and .pem and .mobileprovision .ipa, I really don't know what to do anymore.. Why do we have to convert to .pem and merge them? Is this REALLY the way Apple intended for us to do this? Or have I been following a pretty redicolus tutorial?

What .cer file do I need? Which profile should the app use? AppID vs provision vs device vs Certificate. What the hell.. Should I have to do anything other than switching to a new .pem file and remove the "sandbox". I have activated and downloaded the "Production Push SSL Certificate" from the portal, and generated my .pem file from that. I have tried reading up on this, but it is reeeally hard and a stupid setup! I'm sure I have done something wrong. But can't figure out what, where and why!

Answer (score 0):

[Push notification services](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) - great tutorial, you will find php script + answer for all your questions.

Comment: No, this is exactly the tutorial I used. It was that php-script I removed "sandbox" from, and it said I just had to do the same stuff again. And I did. I believe.

Comment: Ok then, did you setup your Product.entitlements to distribution? aps-environment: distribution, get-task-allow: NO ? My settings which are working are this same like you: $ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ckProduction.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
 $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

Comment: Will that have anything to do with this? I thought this problem occured because I didn't get a connection to the server.. That wouldn't have anything to do with the app? Anyway.. I think everything is set up to distribution. Will re-check tomorrow.